# Android how to select id of autocompletetextview inside onitemclick overridden function

Tags: android, android-listview, autocompletetextview, android-event

I have three `autoCompleteTextView` box as `home` , `work` , `other` .

So in home autocomplete box i get a data from server and select one item and that item i stored to `home_latlong` string. Similarly i have to get value from other autocomplete work which i am storing that value in another string called `home_latlong`. Below code shows `onItemClick` overridden function where i will store `home_latlong` or `work_latlong`.
`

```
ontemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("POSITION ="+position);
        for (int i = 0; i < latlong.size(); i++) {
            if(i==position){
                home_latlong=latlong.get(i);
                System.out.println("ARRAY"+latlong.get(i));
            }
        }
}`
```

So problem is i am not able differenciate when i will store `home_latlong` and when to store `work_latlong`. I tried with id of `autocompletetextview` but it did not help in this function.

Comment: you have adapterView param,  you can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using anonymous inner class ,

```
actv1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
actv1 .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < latlong.size(); i++) {
                if (i == position) {
                    home_latlong = latlong.get(i);
                    System.out.println("ARRAY" + latlong.get(i));
                }

            }
        }

    });
```

Similarly for `work_latlong` i had another anonymous inner class so i can get which autocompleteview i have clicked.

Comment: An other solution is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32392355/2306907).

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html):

> `public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - parent: The AdapterView where the click happened.
> - view: The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)

You need to use the *first* parameter (the AdapterView) to identify the `AutocompleteTextView`.

Comment: With that parent parameter how to identify which of the three autocompleteview ?

Comment: @Naveen You can use `if (parent.getId() == R.id.theIdOfEachView) ...`

Comment: that did not work. I tried if (adapterView.getId() == R.id.autoCompleteTextView1)... Even though i have clicked on autocompleteTextView1 but it is not going inside loop at all.